"Stock" converted to a numeric value
Stock should be converted to a numeric valueBy replacing {stock[1]} by "available " to 100, and "limited stock" to 10, "out of stock" to 0. The idea is to work with numeric values ​​and update stocks.
I am looking for someone that could handle the problem with this dynamic xml file

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In XSLT (1.0 or greater):
<xsl:template match="stock[.='available']">
  <stock>100</stock>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stock[.='limited stock']">
  <stock>10</stock>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stock[.='out of stock']">
  <stock>0</stock>
</xsl:template>

Combined of course with other rules to handle the rest of your content, which you haven't shown us.
